# How to share a Fixture between tests in multiple projects using xUnit.net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xunit.net

Is it possible to share a Fixture between tests in multiple projects using xUnit.net?

Comment: What you mean sharing? Fixture is a class, you can always reuse in different projects

Comment: Share the Fixture instance. A fixture instance can be shared among any test grouped by a Fixture collection. However, its seems like a Fixture collection can only group tests within the same project.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible and no plan to implement it.
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/374